# MySQL sum only new rows

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with this format

```
transaction |  user   | amount | week
------------|---------|--------|------
     1      | user_1  |  100   |  1
     2      | user_2  |   50   |  1
     3      | user_1  |   50   |  2
     4      | user_3  |  200   |  2
```

I know how to calculate the sum amount for each week in MySQL, but is there a way in MySQL to calculate new users sum amount per week?

So for this table it would be:

```
week 1 = 150
week 2 = 200
```

Comment: what do you mean by "new users sum"? why is it 200 and not 250 for week 2?

Comment: What constitutes a new user? One who has not appeared in any previous week?

Comment: Yes, a new user, is one that has not appeared in any previous week

Comment: does any of the answers below solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can use the value of `MIN(week)` to indicate a particular user's first transaction.

```sql
SELECT w, SUM(amount)
FROM(
    SELECT user, amount, MIN(week) AS w
    FROM `trans`
    GROUP BY user) newUserTrans
GROUP BY w
```

If you want to still show a week where there is no new user, then you can use this:

```sql
SELECT week, IFNULL(SUM(amount),0) AS total
FROM(
    SELECT user, amount, MIN(week) AS w
    FROM `trans`
    GROUP BY user) newUserTrans RIGHT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT week FROM trans) weeks ON newUserTrans.w = weeks.week
GROUP BY w
ORDER BY week
```

**UPDATE**:

Based on @skobaljic opinion, I also provide another alternative for the case when a user may have multiple records in the same week.

```sql
SELECT weeks.week AS Week, IFNULL(SUM(amount),0) AS Total
FROM(
    SELECT trans.user, trans.amount, trans.week
    FROM trans
      JOIN (SELECT user, MIN(week) AS w
              FROM trans
              GROUP BY user) newWeek ON trans.user = newWeek.user
           AND trans.week = newWeek.w) newUserTrans
    RIGHT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT week FROM trans) weeks ON newUserTrans.week = weeks.week
GROUP BY newUserTrans.week
ORDER BY weeks.week
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: will it cover more than one transactions per week?

Comment: what do you mean, could you please elaborate, @skobaljic?

Comment: one user can have more transactions in one week, will this sum all of them?

Comment: can it? OP didn't specify it in his question

Comment: for my situation, a user can only have one transaction a week

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could be helpful in any way:

```
select sum(A.`amount`) from `table` AS A WHERE A.`user` NOT IN (SELECT B.`user` FROM `table` AS B where A.`week` > B.`week') AND A.`week` = @pWeek
```

where `@pWeek` is a parameter with a particular number of a week

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better way of get the first week for a user.

First week is the minumum week for a user.

```
select
    trans.week
   ,sum(amount) as amount
from trans
inner join
    (select 
        user
       ,min(week) as firstweek
    from 
        trans
    group by
        user
    ) as firstweek
on  trans.user = firstweek.user
where
    trans.week = firstweek.firstweek
group by 
    trans.week
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM [table] GROUP BY week";
```

this should work. I don't think you will need the sum(amount), but try it both ways.